# Grep a value after a match

Tags: macos, grep, match

I'm using grep on Mac OS X and I want to return the string (token I guess?) after a match. I'm trying to use a command to return my ip address using this command:

```
ifconfig en0 net | grep
```

I'm wanting to return the ip address that follows the inet match.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command

```
ifconfig en0 | grep inet
```

it will return ipv4 as well as ipv6 address

To view only ipv4 address, you can try following

```
ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\  -f2
```

Comment: What if I just wanted ipv

Comment: What if I just wanted IPv4?